# JsonP response code on GWT

Tags: java, json, gwt, jsonp

I'm using GWT 2.3 and I have json-p requests in my code similar to this:

```
JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
jsonp.requestObject(jsonUrl, new AsyncCallback<T>() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) { // error }

  public void onSuccess(T t) { //do something }
});
```

some GET-requests return 200, others 302 and so on, and I should be
able to return a different "answer" respect to this value. How can I
know what's the response value returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not access the response code using the JsonpRequestBuilder. But if you use the standard RequestBuilder instead you can get the response code using getStatusCode(). Of course you have to then the parse the response text yourself.

```
RequestBuilder r = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, jsonUrl);
r.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        // error
    }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            //do something
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == 302) {
            //do something else
        }
    }
});
```